# SQL Query - Repeat the result 5 times with removal of the first row for each reputation for the resultant set

Tags: sql

My current data set

```
+----+-------+
| ID | Value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 40    |
+----+-------+
| 2  | 20    |
+----+-------+
| 3  | 30    |
+----+-------+
| 4  | 60    |
+----+-------+
| 5  | 10    |
+----+-------+
```

Excepted Output:

```
+--------+----+-------+
| Row_ID | ID | Value |
+--------+----+-------+
| 1      | 1  | 40    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 1      | 2  | 20    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 1      | 3  | 30    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 1      | 4  | 60    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 1      | 5  | 10    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 2      | 2  | 20    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 2      | 3  | 30    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 2      | 4  | 60    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 2      | 5  | 10    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 3      | 3  | 30    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 3      | 4  | 60    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 3      | 5  | 10    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 4      | 4  | 60    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 4      | 5  | 10    |
+--------+----+-------+
| 5      | 5  | 10    |
+--------+----+-------+
```

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Use a recursive cte.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did the long way..union all 5 times with where condition added to each union query .

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a self-join:

```
select t.id, t2.id, t2.value
from t join
     t t2
     on t.id <= t2.id;
```